# Deployment of NUXT on IIS the API response 404

Tags: laravel, iis, nuxt.js

I have deployed my NuxtJs project and Laravel Api on IIS Window Server. Previously there was CORS error someone recommended to use proxy but on server the proxy url always response 404 error

Below is my nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'@nuxtjs/auth-next',
'@nuxtjs/proxy'
],
axios: {
baseURL: '/',
proxy: true,
headers: { //optional
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
},
proxy:
  {
    '/api/': { 
      target: 'http://hrmapis.mygwambo.com',
      pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''},
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
```

Comment: How have you configured IIS to work with nuxtjs?

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: @Dai , I have installed NodeJs and pointed dist folder to the domain. The first landing page is opening but whenever any API request happens it response CORS error so I configured nuxt proxy and after configuration, it is giving 404

Comment: @Himanshu that doesn't answer my question: I asked how you configured IIS.

Comment: @Dai I installed IISNode, In nuxt.config I changed to module.exports = {, then I installed npm install nuxt-start, then installed express, then i build the project and in my server folder I have created web.config refered from nuxtjs documentation. 
For domain pointing I have pointed my domain to dist folder

Comment: @Himanshu IISNode hasn't been maintained since 2018 and [the last release was 2016](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases/tag/v0.2.21)... I don't think you want to be running that.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I removed this, the main problem is my project is running it is opening first landing page but whenever any API call happen it is responding 404. I am using proxy

Comment: The error log doesn't show the key factor that lead to this 404 error, please enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) and post the error log here, it will provide the key error and warning.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nuxtjs You can try the steps with HttpPlatformHandler/IIS.